# link_to with nested resources edit_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, link-to

In my routes I have:

```
    resources :users do
      resources :orders
    end
```

so when I create a link which leads to 'show' action I can simply make

```
<%= link_to "Details", [@order.user, @order] %>
```

But what should I write if I want to make `link_to` for 'edit' action?

in my orders_controller:

```
@order = Order.find params[:id]
```

so I've tried this code:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_order_path([@order.user, @order]) %>
```

but somehow `edit_user_order_path` method can't get :id parameter from `@order` object, error says me:

> missing required keys: [:id]

while `user_id` is returning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`edit_user_order_path(@order.user, @order)`

Comment: well yea, it worked! bun not exactly this way, this code will work: edit_user_order_path(@order.user, @order), i tryed to send data in an array format while it needed just two separate arguments!